# merging list with nested list

Tags: python, json

I need to 'cross join' (for want of a better term !) 2 lists.
Between them they represent a tabled dataset but ..
One holds the column header names, the other a nested array with the row values.

I've managed the easy bit :

```
col_names = [i['name'] for i in c]
```

which strips the column names out in to a list without 'typeName'

But just thinking how to extract the row field values and map them with column names .. is giving me a headache!

Any pointers appreciated ;)
Thanks

Columns (as provided):

```
[
{
    "name": "col1",
    "typeName": "varchar"
},
{
    "name": "col2",
    "typeName": "int4"
}
```

]

Records (as provided):

```
[
    [
        {
            "stringValue": "apples"
        },
        {
            "longValue": 1
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "stringValue": "bananas"
        },
        {
            "longValue": 2
        }
    ]
]
```

---

Required Result:

```
[
    {
        'col1':'apples',
        'col2':1
    },
    {
        'col1':'bananas',
        'col2':2
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you sure that's how your data looks, a list of lists of separate dictionaries?  I would have expected "stringValue" and "longValue" to be part of the same dictionary.

Comment: Aye, it's a pain.

Comment: Aye, it's a pain. Each table row is a list & each field within is its own dic. Full schema on link but you have to scroll down to 'response syntax'.   https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift-data.html#RedshiftDataAPIService.Client.get_statement_result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be able to assume there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between the names in the schema and the dicts in the records.  Once you assume that, it's pretty easy:

```
names = [i['name'] for i in schema]

data = []
for row in records:
    d = {}
    for a,b in zip( names, row ):
        d[a] = list(b.values())[0]
    data.append(d)
print(data)
```